# Uninstalling Ipython-0.12 on OS X

Tags: uninstallation, ipython

I have upgraded from OS 10.6 to 10.8, and done a full new installation of Xcode Command Line Tools, MacPorts, and Pip. I have used Pip to install Ipython-0.13, which runs when I open it from its own directory; but when I type `ipython` at the command line, only an old version of Ipython-0.12 opens from the /Applications directory. Manually deleting that old version and then typing `ipython` brings an error message

```
python: can't open file '/Applications/ipython-0.12/ipython.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

and no uninstall/remove commands to Pip or MacPorts result in an uninstall of this old version (naturally, since the old version was not installed with Pip or MacPorts).

What do I need to do so that ipython-0.12 is gone and forgotten, and `ipython` at the command line starts the most current version? Where is python looking to find the current version of Ipython, and how do I update that manually?

Comment: I think SO lets you answer your own question and accept the answer, so that the question shows up as having an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was pilot error. My `.bash_profile` contained an alias assigning ipython-0.12 to the name `ipython`. When I removed it and rebooted, all was well.